# Sum operations using while loops

Tags: java, loops

I am calculating the sum between two bounds (using increments) but I am not getting the appropiate output:

Example 1:

```
First: 3
Last: 5
Sum is: 12
```

Example 2:

```
First: 2
Last: 8
Sum is: 35
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("First: ");
    int x = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    System.out.print("Second: ");
    int y = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    int i = x;
    int result = 0;

    while (i < y){
        result += i + 1;
        i++;

        System.out.println("Sum is " + result);
```

Wrong output:

```
First: 3
Second: 5
Sum is: 9
```

Comment: Stop rolling back. Your question is *not* about JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

you're effectively skipping the first iteration where you add the `3`

```
result += i + 1;
i++;
```

in your 3, 5 example `i` starts off as `3`, and since your first iteration adds `i+1` to your `result`, you are adding `4`

in your last iteration, `i` will be 4, and you will be adding `4+1` to `result`, that's why your actual result is `3` less than your expected result.

If I were you, I'd build your result like this

```
for(int i = x; i<= y; i++)
{
    result += i;
}
```

<sub>*Since your `while` loop prints the incremental sum after every iteration, you should have seen this behavior.</sub>

Comment: Thank you that actually makes a lot more sense to me now!  That build makes more sense to me actaully then what I was doing before!